# How to capture a period within an optional block

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Strings and wish to capture numbers only including decimal points.

So want to capture following type of numbers.

```
1
10
100
10.20
```

This is the regex which works for the Strings at the end.

Regex

```
(\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?!\.)
```

See below where I have other Strings which all works less the following String.

```
$0 text $99.<sup>&#164;</sup>
```

This is cos the $99 is followed by a `.` It is not a decimal thus I don't want to capture it plus it is optional, not always gonna occur. How could I modify the regex so that I can still capture the value `99` in above String as `matcher 2`?

Comment: Replace `\b(?!\.)` with `(?!\.?\d)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect, works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\.?\d)
```

The `(?!\.?\d)` lookahead will only fail if there is an optional dot and then a digit immediately to the right of the current location.